# What does the Fixed Frame mean in rviz?

Tags: ros, rviz, frame

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What does the Fixed Frame mean in rviz?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197740/what-does-the-fixed-frame-mean-in-rviz?/) by [somebodyus](https://answers.ros.org/users/20767/somebodyus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2014-11-19

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's the [tf](http://wiki.ros.org/tf) frame that all positions/measurements that you see are relative to. For example, let's say you have a robot that has two frames, *odom* (a world-fixed frame) and *base_link* (the body frame of the robot). The robot is at position `(10, 0)` with a heading of `pi/2` in the *odom* frame, and it has a LIDAR on board that sees an obstacle 5 meters directly in front of it. If you set your Fixed Frame to *odom*, that obstacle will appear at position `(10, 5)`. If you set your Fixed Frame to base_link, it will appear at `(5, 0)`.

EDIT: updating answer for comment from @malharjajoo

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2014-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [somebodyus](https://answers.ros.org/users/20767/somebodyus/) on 2014-11-19**:
Thank you so much.

Does the `Grid` always be the world coordinate? If I set `/odom` as the fixed frame. Rviz will draw obstacle at potions `(10, 5)` in the `Grid`?

I think the heading in your assumption should be `pi/2`.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-11-19**:
Yeah, fixed that, sorry. Need coffee.

And yes, if you set the fixed frame to /odom, the obstacle will be drawn at (10, 5).

**Comment by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on 2018-02-07**:
@Tom, I didn;t really follow your explanation, what does heading = pi/2 mean ( is the robot facing left by 90 degree compared to lidar) ?

also could you elaborate how the (10,0) and (10,5) works out ? can't seem to visualize that based on the explanation.

**Comment by [Nagarjun](https://answers.ros.org/users/47555/nagarjun/) on 2020-10-14**:
What happens If I keep my fixed_frame as /map instead of /odom and /base_link frame?

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2020-10-19**:
Then you will see everything displayed in the map frame. In my drawing, just imagine another coordinate frame like the odom frame, but not with the same origin/position.

All the fixed frame does is define where the origin is when rviz displays things.

**Comment by [Anshul](https://answers.ros.org/users/47131/anshul/) on 2021-04-23**:
I'll just write what I understood from this, let me know if I'm wrong. So the `map` frame is linked to the environment and the `odom` frame is linked to the starting point of the robot on the map.